# How to remove header bar after purge Ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I have installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` in Ubuntu 14.04(unity). After couple of days I decided to remove `gnome-shell`. So I run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But now in `Ubuntu desktop(unity)`, some `gtk3 applications`(nautilus, gnome-terminal, system-settings etc) are using `header bar` (which is default in `gnome-shell`). How to get rid of this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't purge(remove) the right package at the first place. As a result some gnome packages(from gnome-shell) were installed in my system and conflict with `unity`(theme). So I took the following steps.

## Remove all gnome packages

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-*
```

It will also remove some applications and breaks `unity`. So to fix the side affect I reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

It solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Purge the `gnome-shell`. `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is only a meta package and removes nothing.
After that, you should install Unity again, it could be broken.

*Sample output*

```
% sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gnome-shell-extensions
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop*
```

---

Purge `gnome-shell` with the command below

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
```

*Sample output* on my machine

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cgmanager geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas indicator-applet indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session
  indicator-sound libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1 libcgmanager0 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libjson0 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libpanel-applet0
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 lightdm signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signon-ui-service
  signon-ui-x11 signond systemd-shim ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart upstart-bin
Suggested packages:
  click powerd unity-system-compositor unity-greeter-session-broadcast fcitx url-dispatcher lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure remote-login-service graphviz upstart-monitor
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm* gnome-shell* gnome-shell-extensions* ubuntu-gnome-desktop*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cgmanager geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas indicator-applet indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session
  indicator-sound libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1 libcgmanager0 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libjson0 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libpanel-applet0
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 lightdm signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signon-ui-service
  signon-ui-x11 signond systemd-shim ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart upstart-bin
```

Comment: Nope doesn't help.